# unable to send messages to graylog server using logstash

Tags: logstash, graylog2, graylog

I am using logstash to send messages to graylog server. I have been successful in sending messages directly to elasticsearch or stdout or loggly. I have also been successful in sending messages to graylog server using cURL.

```
curl -XPOST http://graylog.example.org:12202/gelf -p0 -d '{"short_message":"Hello there", "host":"example.org", "facility":"test", "_foo":"bar"}'
```

Here is the command I am using to send data using logstash to graylog

```
bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin {} } output { gelf {host => "graylog.example.org" port => 12202 } }' < LOG-10
```

File LOG-10 has log messages. I have tried port 12201 too. I looked into debug messages from logstash but that was also not useful.

Comment: Test the connectivity from the logstash machine to the graylog machine on that port (telnet or nc).  Check the graylog logs.

Comment: I am running curl and logstash on same machine and using same port. I did not see any thing in graylog logs corresponding to logstash. I am investigating port traffic, do you happen to know any good tools (netstat, tcpdump)? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that logstash gelf.rb is not using TCP, but UDP. https://github.com/Graylog2/gelf-rb/pull/21

I had to add "GELF UDP" as one of the graylog message input (responsible for accepting log messages). This can be accessed from graylog web interface system inputs. [image]